# Why is "wieviele" not recognized as a word in my spell checker?

Tags: spelling

When I write the word "wieviele" in my German spell checker (Thunderbird), it tells me it is an error:

[image]

Although a quick search at [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?sourceoverride=none&source=auto&query=wieviele) tells me that it is an often-used word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Wieviel" is the *alte Rechtschreibung*. The modern spelling is "wie viel". "Wie viele" is  written as two words, both in the old and new spelling.